# Creation of new todos code generating error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, error-handling

I'm building a simple project of todo list using jQuery 2.4.1 min version but the creation of new todos is giving me the following error:

```
todos.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: event.stopPropogation is not a function
at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (todos.js:12)
at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ todos.js:12
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

Js file:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");

});

$("ul").on("click","span",function(event){

    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

event.stopPropogation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){

    if(event.which === 13)
    {
        var todosText=$(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span>X<span> " + todosText + "<li>");

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a spelling mistake in `event.stopPropogation()`. You must write `event.stopPropagation()`. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, it did remove the error but the creation of new todos still isn't functioning properly.

Comment: You are also missing ‘/‘ in closing tags while appending html. Like for closing tag for <li>, it should be </li>. Same goes for <span>.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you're continuing to have issues, you should make a new question.